# F# tail recursion with monadic bind

Tags: f#, bind, monads, tail-recursion

Using the Writer monad:

```
type Writer< 'w, 'a when 'w : (static member add: 'w * 'w -> 'w) 
                    and  'w : (static member zero: unit -> 'w) > = 

    | Writer of 'a * 'w
```

with bind:

```
let inline bind ma fm =
    let (Writer (a, log1)) = ma 
    let mb = fm a
    let (Writer (b, log2)) = mb
    let sum = ( ^w : (static member add :  ^w * ^w -> ^w) (log1, log2) )
    Writer (b, sum)
```

If I have a recursive function (convergence, Newton's method) with each iteration binding Writer results, I think this must not be tail recursive (even though it may look like it judged just from the recursive call):

```
let solve params =
    let rec solve guess iteration = 
        let (adjustment : Writer<Error,float>) = getAdjustment params guess
        let nextStep adjustment = 
            if (abs adjustment) <= (abs params.tolerance) then
                Writer.rtn guess
            elif iteration > params.maxIter then
                Writer (0.0, Error.OverMaxIter)
            else
                solve (guess + adjustment) (iteration + 1)

        adjustment >>= nextStep

    sovle params.guess 1
```

because all the logs have to be held in a queue until the recursion ends (and then joined).

So one question is whether it's correct that the bind on Writer makes the recursion not a tail call. A second question is whether switching to the Either monad:

```
type Result<'e, 'a> = 
    | Ok of 'a
    | Err of 'e
```

with bind:

```
let bind ma fm =
    match ma with 
    | Ok a  -> fm a
    | Err e -> Err e
```

will make this now be tail recursive:

```
//...
        let (adjustment : Result<Error,float>) = getAdjustment params guess
        let nextStep adjustment = 
            if (abs adjustment) <= (abs params.tolerance) then
                Result.rtn guess
            elif iteration > params.maxIter then
                Result.fail Error.OverMaxIter
            else
                solve (guess + adjustment) (iteration + 1)

        adjustment >>= nextStep
//...
```

Since the logic of Either's bind is short circuiting? Or could that `adjustment >>=` hold onto a stack position?

EDIT:

So in light of the clear answer, I can clarify and answer my question--which now amounts to something like whether tail call position is "transitive". (1) The recursive call to `nextStep` is a tail call in `nextStep`. (2) The (initial) call to `nextStep` is a tail call in `bind` (of my `Either`/`Result` monad). (3) `bind` is a tail call in the outer (recursive) `solve` function.

Does the tail call analysis and optimization carry through this nesting? Yes.

Comment: Assuming you've defined your `>>=` operator as being a simple call to `bind`, the line `adjustment >>= nextStep` is exactly equivalent to `bind adjustment nextStep`: it will hold on to a stack frame if and **only** if the function does more work. Since here, the `bind` call is in tail position, there won't be an extra stack frame. See my answer below for more.

Comment: Yes it's as you say for the operator: `let (>>=) ma fm = Result.bind ma fm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually very simple to tell if a function call is tail-recursive: just see if the calling function needs to do other work after that call, or if that call is in tail position (i.e., it's the last thing the function does, and the result of that call is also the result returned by the calling function). This can be done with simple static code analysis, with no understanding of what the code does -- which is why the compiler is able to do it, and to produce proper `.tail` opcodes in the .DLL it produces.

You're correct that the `bind` function for `Writer` can't call its `fm` parameter in a tail-recursive way -- and the proof of that is very simple when you look at the implementation of `bind` that you wrote in your question:

```
let inline bind ma fm =
    let (Writer (a, log1)) = ma 
    let mb = fm a   // <--- here's the call
    let (Writer (b, log2)) = mb   // <--- more work after the call
    let sum = ( ^w : (static member add :  ^w * ^w -> ^w) (log1, log2) )
    Writer (b, sum)
```

That's all I need to look at. Because the call to `fm` isn't the last thing the `bind` function does (i.e., it isn't in *tail position*), I know that that call isn't tail-recursive and will use up a stack frame.

Now let's look at the `bind` implementation for `Result`:

```
let bind ma fm =
    match ma with 
    | Ok a  -> fm a  // <--- here's the call
    | Err e -> Err e // <--- not the same code branch
    // <--- no more work!
```

So in this implementation of `bind`, the call to `fm` is the last thing the function does along that code branch, and the result of `fm` is therefore the result of `bind`. So the compiler will convert the call to `fm` into a proper tail call, and it won't take up a stack frame.

Now let's look one level out, where you call `bind`. (Well, you use the `>>=` operator, but I assume that you've defined it as `let (>>=) ma fm = bind ma fm`, or something equivalent. **NOTE:** If your definition is significantly different than that, then my analysis below won't be correct.) Your call to `bind` looks like this:

```
let rec solve guess iteration =
    // Definition of `nextStep` that calls `solve` in tail position
    adjustment >>= nextStep
```

The line `adjustment >>= nextStep` is exactly equivalent to `bind adjustment nextStep` from the compiler's point of view. So for the sake of this tail-position code analysis, we'll pretend that that line is `bind adjustment nextStep`.

Assuming that that's the entire definition of `solve` and there isn't other code below that you haven't shown us, that call to `bind` is in tail position, so it will not consume a stack frame. And `bind` calls `fm` (which here is `nextStep`) in tail position. And `nextStep` calls `solve` in tail position. So you have a properly tail-recursive algorithm, and you won't blow the stack no matter how many adjustments you have to go through.

Comment: Nice analysis. Thanks. I see how the analysis of final position carries, or flows, through all the scopes. It's more than focusing on the specific location of a call to a recursively declared function. Great help. Thanks again.